# C++ / Boost Filesystem - mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, boost-filesystem

I'm new to C++ and Boost. I'm doing a small simple program to trying to learn the Boost Filesystem library. I have followed the directions to build the Boost libs. And now when I try to compile this simple code I get 6 of these errors.

```
Error   5   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in App.obj C:\SOURCE\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib(codecvt_error_category.obj)  ConsoleApp2  
Error   1   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in App.obj C:\SOURCE\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib(operations.obj)  ConsoleApp2  
Error   2   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in App.obj C:\SOURCE\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib(path.obj)    ConsoleApp2  
Error   3   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in App.obj C:\SOURCE\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib(path_traits.obj) ConsoleApp2  
Error   4   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in App.obj C:\SOURCE\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib(windows_file_codecvt.obj)    ConsoleApp2  
Error   6   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib'  C:\SOURCE\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\LINK  ConsoleApp2
```

My code in `App.cpp` in my ConsoleApp2 project

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(void) 
{
    path p = "C:\\TestFiles";
    cout << is_directory(p);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to compile the app with Visual Studio 2010. Some of the info I have found online were related to VS 2012. This I don't think applies to me. I'd like to try to solve the 5 mismatch errors and the final link error. I'm hoping the last error is related to the 5 before it.

Comment: Probably while building the library, you should specify the `toolset` option to `10.0`. Since it is compiled with VS 2012, it takes `11.0` by default. This forces the libs to be used with VS 2012 alone. This is out of my experience. If you wish to use it with VS 2010, specify the toolset option to 10.0 and the libraries will be correctly built.

Comment: There is very similar answered issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575747/error-lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-msc-ver-value-1600-doesnt-match-valu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_51.lib` is a library that has been built with VS 2012 (Also known as VC 11.0), as indicated by the `vc110` in the naming convention.  This library will not link properly with objects built with VS 2010 (also known as VC 10.0).

If you want to build your program with VS 2010, you'll need to get or build boost libraries for VS 2010.

Comment: A commonly referred to source for pre-built boost libraries for various versions of MSVC is: http://boost.teeks99.com/

Comment: How do I build it with vs2012 when I don't have it installed? I followed the instructions here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/windows.html but did not pass in a --toolset param. Should I rerun the bjam with the --toolset=msvc=10.0

Comment: Just noticed this was @Mahesh's comment on the question too.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have VS2012 installed?  What does running `set vs11` in a command window on your system say?  Did you download boost from somewhere that might have had pre-built libraries?

Comment: I was running vs11 on one machine at home. And not on my home computer. This was throwing me off. I was able to fix the issue at least on my home computer by getting the pre-built binaries. Is there a good place to pick up the vs11 binaries?

Comment: http://boost.teeks99.com/ has vc11-built libraries for boost 1.51.  There's a comment that they're 'unsupported', but the linked message indicates that the unsupported patch looks pretty benign. Minor disclaimer: I haven't tried them.

Answer (score 4):

Open the `*.vcxproj` file with a text editor.

Find and delete the `<_ProjectFileVersion>` element, and then save the file.

Example,

```
</ImportGroup>
<ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
  <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
</ImportGroup>
<PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
<PropertyGroup>

  <_ProjectFileVersion>11.0.30319.1</_ProjectFileVersion> <--- Delete this element

</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
```

And rebuild the solution again. You will see the project compiling successfully.

Comment: My project vcxproj file does not have this tag! What other options I have?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to compile the Teamcenter ITK C++ code and got the same error message:

> error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't
>   match value '1600' in itk_main.obj

The workaround I did was searching for msvcprt.lib sitting somewhere in c:
(used everything.exe to search, which can be found on voidtools.com)

Opened that file in NP++ or text editor search for keyword _MSC_VER and changed the value /FAILIFMISMATCH:"_MSC_VER=1700"  to /FAILIFMISMATCH:"_MSC_VER=1600"

And yes, I was able to compile.

Answer (score -1):

solution mentioned by vignesh naidu worked for me.

but not exactly msvcprt.lib

look for the .lib file in the error msg.

In my case, there was somefile.lib ,
i searched in the file explorer which gave two similar files in folder

1)Release
2)Debug

Opened somefile.lib in debug folder, opened in NP++ , found and replaced 
for ex: 1700 with 1900 (VS 2015) in my case

recompiled, viola error gone.

For brief explanation about why,how there are several technical reasons given by other users.

PS: i was compiling code built in VS 2012 in VS2015 and 1700 is compiler version for VS 2012 , 1900 for VS 2015