# Error LNK2038 at VS2012

Tags: cplex

I am using the Visual Studio 2012 with CPLEX 12.6, in 32bits but my computer is 64bits. I had this error for 53 times.

```
Error   2   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Source.obj   C:\Users\freca\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\project3\project3\concert.lib(ilotypes.obj)    project3
```

What can i do to fix this? Its about the Runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '\_MSC\_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in CppFile1.obj](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575747/error-lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-msc-ver-value-1600-doesnt-match-valu)

Comment: Try building the examples. Then compare the settings from the example projects with your own.