# Unresolved external symbol error from generated protobuf C++ code on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, c++17, protocol-buffers

I am building a shared library (DLL) that includes Protobuf generated C++ code.

Below is the example proto.

Sample.proto

```
message Request {
  float id = 1;
  float name = 2;
}
```

The protobuf C++ code generation and DLL creation happens successfully. However, when I try to link this library to an application, it throws the below error:

```
app.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl Sample::Request::
~Request(void)" (??Request@sample@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main [C:\Us
ers\sample\sample\out\app\build\app.vcxproj]


app.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl Sample::Request::
vftable" (??Request@sample@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main [C:\Us
ers\sample\out\app\build\app.vcxproj]
```

I believe the symbols are not properly exported from the Protobuf generated code. I tried specifying the `set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)` and other errors disappear except `vftable`. I tried searching if there is a way to export symbols when generating protobuf code but didn't see an option to do it.

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Some module is missing from the linking stage - you'll need to show how you build.

Comment: is `Sample.pb.cc` a part compilation?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, it is part of the compilation. Also, as I said, enabling set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE) in CMakeLists.txt fixes one of these errors but vftable error is still showing.

Comment: sounds like you have "inline everything" flag on

Comment: it's not very good design anyway if dll's client is dependant on your generated headers, on protobuf headers and on previse version of runtime which was usedd for .dll

Comment: Yeah, I see inline functions in the generated protobuf code. I read set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE) doesn't work on inline functions but I am not sure how to turn off inline functions when generating protobuf code.

Comment: Some info here, but somewhat old. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900268/statically-link-google-protobuf-lib-into-a-dll-library Afaik it never was meant to be used like that, in exposed way. Protobuf is "wire format" wrapper and exposing it as part of higher level API is kindof odd. One thing that is important that library uses global storage and states.

Comment: Is `Sample` class marked as `__declspec(dllexport)`?

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko `Request@sample` points at that it is a namespace...  probably module of protobuf definition in .proto

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Right, thanks for correcting. I meant the `Request` class. Author must ensure that it is exported.